# LaTeX and graphviz: "no room for a new \write"

Tags: diagrams, shell-escape, graphs

I'm using [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/) on Mac OS X (based on LaTeX) in conjunction with the [graphvizzz](http://code.google.com/p/graphvizzz/) package in order to draw inline directed graphs in my documents (with the use of write18 and the `dot` command). Apparently each graph uses a `\write` command, so I got up to about a dozen inline graphs in a single document and ran out of `\write` slots. When I try to build the document, I now get the following error:

```
? ! No room for a new \write .
```

I've [done](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-noroom) [some](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2007-March/013292.html) [reading](http://email.esm.psu.edu/pipermail/macosx-tex/2007-April/030378.html) about this problem, and there's no immediately apparent way to increase the number of `\write`s available to me. Is there another way I can continue to use this package without requiring a `\write` for each graph?

For reference, a sample document looks something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphvizzz}

\begin{document}

This is a state machine:
\digraph[scale=0.5]{machine}{
   margin = "0 0 0 0";
   rankdir = "LR";
   node [ shape = "circle" ] A B;
   A -> B [ label = "0" ];
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) you could evade this problem.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}
  This is a state machine:

  \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    >=stealth,
    node distance=2cm,
    on grid,
    auto
  ]
    \node[state] (A)              {A};
    \node[state] (B) [right of=A] {B};
    \path[->] (A) edge node {0} (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The package manual has the details. There is also a [specific example gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/automata-and-petri-nets/).

---

[image]

Comment: This looks like a much better solution than what I'm currently using - I'll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The package was obviously never tried by its author for anything but trivia.

To put it right, change

```
\newcommand{\digraph}[3][scale=1]{ 
  \newwrite\dotfile 
  ...
```

in the package to

```
\newwrite\dotfile
\newcommand{\digraph}[3][scale=1]{
  ...
```

(i.e., move the `\newwrite` out of the command). Some lines below, remove the `\newwrite\dotfile` line from the definition of `\graph`.

FWIW, you're right; there *is* no way to increase the number of `\write` streams. and of course, using TikZ is a good alternative, so carry on with that if it suits you.

Comment: I was thinking of suggesting (reminding?) either you or the OP to make sure this gets reported to the package author, but I see that someone has already reported it as http://code.google.com/p/graphvizzz/issues/detail?id=1, with a link straight here for the fix. Good job, whoever it was.

Comment: I actually handled it - thanks anon for suggesting the change, or I wouldn't have thought to report it as an issue in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, this got me to inspect the sty file, noting that there is now an option that you can pass to usepackage: `singlefile` which did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `morewrites` packages:

http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/morewrites/morewrites.pdf

Basically, all you need to do is to add the line

`\usepackage{morewrites}`

somewhere near the beginning of your document and the "No more room for a new \write" error should disappear.

Comment: While this can be a useful tip in general, the "real" solution to the particular problem is to correct a the clearly faulty package, taking out the `\newwrite\dotfile` declarations from the definitions of `\digraph` and `\graph` and issuing it once and for all at the start. This will cooperate well with `morewrites`, of course. Unfortunately, the bug hasn't been corrected in almost 18 months.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX has a limit of 16 open files, and many packages open them.

There are 3 solutions for this error:

- Use LuaLaTeX, and the limit will be the limit in the operating systems (never tried)
- Use the packages morewrites (used it for a while but later hit in a bug)
- Use the package scrwfile from KOMA-Script (my current, and smoothly running, choice)

morewrites and scrwfile have different approaches to solve this problem, but both change the LaTeX kernel somehow. Deep Magic.