# "No room for a new \read" with writing a journal

Tags: macros, errors, packages

I'm fairly new to TeX and learning as I go. I am trying to keep a journal in LaTeX. I'm using the solution provided at  [Using LaTeX to keep a diary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68525/using-latex-to-keep-a-diary) . It's essentially a setup where each day's entry is stored in a new file.

I hit the `No room for a new \read` error at entry 14. It seems like there are only so many files that I can include like this. Even then 14 sounds like a very small number. Is there a solution to this? A solution which will let me go on for years, adding thousands of entries. I have looked at [No room for a new \read/\write](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64372/no-room-for-a-new-read-write) which seems to discuss this or similar issue. But I'm not sure how to fix this code.

I have put the code in `journal.tex` file. In the same directory there is a folder called 2013, which contains a folder called Jan, which contains 14 `.tex` files `1.tex` - `14.tex`. All of them are completely empty.

`journal.tex` follows.

```
%This file layout courtesy of the following online recipe
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68525/using-latex-to-keep-a-diary

\documentclass{tufte-book}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{minted}


\newenvironment{loggentry}[2]% date, heading
{\noindent\textbf{#2}\marginnote{#1}\par}{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\def\?#1{}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\StartYear}{2012}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\EndYear}{2013}

\newcommand{\writetitle}{0}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]
{   \ifthenelse{\writetitle=1}{#1}{}
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \Year in {\StartYear,...,\EndYear}
{   \foreach \Month in {Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec}
    {   \foreach \Day in {1,...,31}
        {   \IfFileExists{\Year/\Month/\Day}
                {   \newread\mysource
                    \openin\mysource=\Year/\Month/\Day.tex
                    \read\mysource to \firstline
                    \closein\mysource
                    \xdef\writetitle{1}
                    \begin{loggentry}{\Year - \Month - \Day}{\firstline}    
                        \xdef\writetitle{0}
                        \input{\Year/\Month/\Day}
                    \end{loggentry} 
                }
                {   % files does not exist, so nothing to do
                }
        }  
    }
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64372/no-room-for-a-new-read-write covers this to some extent, but perhaps without enough detail for the non-expert!

Comment: yeah I had looked at that question but couldn't understand if any of that info, applied, and how.

Comment: OK, I suspected as much. Answer coming up if no-one beats me :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TeX allows only 16 file streams for reading. These are the 'lowest level' structures, and limit how many files can be read from at one go. However, this does *not* mean that you can only use 16 files! Assuming you need to read one line at a time (*i.e.* that you can' just `\input` the entire subfile), what you want is a single stream for reading, as you don't need to read from more than one file at a time. Thus instead of

```
\foreach \Year in {\StartYear,...,\EndYear}
{   \foreach \Month in {Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec}
    {   \foreach \Day in {1,...,31}
        {   \IfFileExists{\Year/\Month/\Day}
                {   \newread\mysource
                    \openin\mysource=\Year/\Month/\Day.tex
                    \read\mysource to \firstline
                    \closein\mysource
                    \xdef\writetitle{1}
                    \begin{loggentry}{\Year - \Month - \Day}{\firstline}    
                        \xdef\writetitle{0}
                        \input{\Year/\Month/\Day}
                    \end{loggentry} 
                }
                {   % files does not exist, so nothing to do
                }
        }  
    }
}
```

you want

```
\foreach \Year in {\StartYear,...,\EndYear}
{   \foreach \Month in {Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec}
    {   \foreach \Day in {1,...,31}
        {   \IfFileExists{\Year/\Month/\Day}
                {  % Line removed here
                    \openin\mysource=\Year/\Month/\Day.tex
                    \read\mysource to \firstline
                    \closein\mysource
                    \xdef\writetitle{1}
                    \begin{loggentry}{\Year - \Month - \Day}{\firstline}    
                        \xdef\writetitle{0}
                        \input{\Year/\Month/\Day}
                    \end{loggentry} 
                }
                {   % files does not exist, so nothing to do
                }
        }  
    }
}
```

with the line

```
\newread\mysource
```

moved *outside* of the loop: I'd put it in the preamble.

Comment: The same applies to `\write` streams: there are a maximum of 16. It's possible to use a 'pool' of streams so that user code is very unlikely to run out, but this is not set up by the LaTeX2e kernel.

Comment: you mean \newread\mysource followed by \foreach \Year in...?

Comment: OK THAT worked perfectly for 14 files! Hopefully it'll work for 1014 files also... Thanks for a quick and accurate response.

Comment: @Spundun Well possibly yes, but as creating a read is a global thing (for the entire document), 'good style' would be to put that line in the preamble.

Comment: ummm, what's a preamble, the part before \begin{document} ? (I feel highly silly asking this question :) )

Comment: @Spundun Yes: preamble is the 'before the document' part which is used for set-up.

Comment: Ok, done, works. :)

Comment: @JosephWright Oh, /me thought I'd finally have a use case for an extension of `morewrites` to cover reads.