# \includesvg produces "No room for a new \read"

Tags: shell-escape, svg, proofreading

I've already searched a lot about it and I'm aware of both questions ["No room for a new \read" with writing a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94524/no-room-for-a-new-read-with-writing-a-journal) and [No room for a new \read/\write](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64372/no-room-for-a-new-read-write). Still, I couldn't find a solution to my problem since I'm using the SVG package to include .svg files. The package *morewrites* helped stopping **"No room for a new \write"** error messages while e-Tex extensions didn't help with \read (also mentioned [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-noroom)). The include command is entered as follows:

```
\includesvg[clean,pdf]{SVG_File}
```

The *clean* option remove the temporary files produced when extracting *pdf* from svg.

It turned out that the extraction and the cleaning option are producing the problem (removing them turned off the error messages!).

Having a quick look at the SVG implementation, it appears that calling these options invokes more *\immediate\write18* commands. I'm not sure if this command was producing the reading error, but if so, I cannot see how a writing command would request a reading one!

Any hints?

Comment: looking at the source of the package it does a `\newread` on every `\includesvg` that's just wrong:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You did well to find that: the code is horribly laid out!

Comment: @JosephWright well I assumed that was the problem and searched for it, so only looked at a couple of lines:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As David Carlisle points out, the error is in the fact that `\includesvg` calls `\newread\SVG@in@file` at every call (and also does `\newwrite\SVG@out@file`.

This is a big error, because LaTeX doesn't free an allocated output/input stream after usage.

You can fix the bad behavior by patching `\@includesvg`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newread\SVG@in@file
\newwrite\SVG@out@file
\patchcmd{\@includesvg}{\newread\SVG@in@file}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@includesvg}{\newwrite\SVG@out@file}{}{}{}
\makeatother

...<the rest of the document>...
```

This allocates the streams once and for all, removing the bad code from the macro.

You should point out this bug to the package maintainer.

Comment: That worked! Still, I cannot figure out why removing the options also made the error disappear.

Comment: @MhdMayya The `\read` stream is allocated only when the `clean` option is present. So overflowing the number of `\read` stream doesn't happen. Loading `morewrite` helps alleviating the symptoms, but it doesn't cure the disease.